# how can I make the json format like that use json-lib?

Tags: java, json, json-lib

I print the json string  use this code:

```
fatherList.put("totalPage",il.size());
il=item.loadList(si,ps," a.cat_id ="+itemCat," a.id ");

List itemsList=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<il.size();i++)
{
    item=il.get(i);
     Map childMap = new HashMap();  
    childMap.put("id",item.getId());
    childMap.put("name",item.getName());

    childMap.put("part_number",item.getPartNumber());
    childMap.put("check",false);
    itemsList.add(childMap);


}

    fatherList.put("items",itemsList);
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( fatherList );  
    out.print( jsonArray );
```

I put **items** and **totalPage** to the `map`, and in the **items**,there are other `map` in a `ArrayList`..

and now the result look like:  it's array on the root

```
[{
    "items" : [{
            "id" : 1669,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101669"
        }, {
            "id" : 1670,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101670"
        }, {
            "id" : 1671,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101671"
        }, {
            "id" : 1672,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101672"
        }, {
            "id" : 1673,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101673"
        }, {
            "id" : 1674,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101674"
        }, {
            "id" : 1675,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101675"
        }, {
            "id" : 1676,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101676"
        }, {
            "id" : 1677,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101677"
        }, {
            "id" : 1678,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101678"
        }, {
            "id" : 1679,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101679"
        }, {
            "id" : 1680,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101680"
        }, {
            "id" : 1681,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2168mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101681"
        }, {
            "id" : 1682,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2168mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101682"
        }, {
            "id" : 1683,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101683"
        }, {
            "id" : 1684,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101684"
        }, {
            "id" : 1685,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101685"
        }, {
            "id" : 1686,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "1850mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101686"
        }, {
            "id" : 1687,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2168mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101687"
        }, {
            "id" : 1688,
            "check" : false,
            "name" : "2168mm趟门衣柜",
            "part_number" : "DP101688"
        }
    ],
    "totalPage" : 134
}]
```

but I want the result format is like that:

```
    { "totalPage": 134, "items": [{
                "id" : 1669,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101669"
            }, {
                "id" : 1670,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101670"
            }
       ]}
```

how can I do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("totalPage",il.size());
jsonObject.put("items",itemsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( fatherList );
```

If you don't want an array, don't make one.

The order of properties within a JSON object does not matter.

Comment: dont make one so how can I　put the totalPage and items together?? . And not the order problem. my meaning is there are **[]** around the json string..  I can use the `substring`  to delete it , but it has the better method to convert it?

Comment: @chanjianyi: You're already putting those two properties together in a JSON _object_ (in your `fatherList` variable).  You don't want to put that object in an array.